# Несколько ссылок в TextView не работают

Tags: java, android, html, строки, textview

Например: `<a href="https://youtu.be/wGWZRAAvzkU?t=1m11s" target="_blank">`Для компьютера не существуют языков программирования. Для него есть 1 и 0 - бинарный код, который он передает процессору, который обрабатывает этот код.`</a>`
        `<a href="https://youtu.be/wGWZRAAvzkU?t=1m55s" target="_blank">`Язык программирования - связующее между компьютером и человеком. `</a>`

Это все я вставлю в один `TextView` из `String`:

```
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString((R.string.btn1javaA1))));
```

Но ссылки не работают

Comment: это же html разметка. как она будет работать в TextView? Ставьте ее тогда в WebView)))

Comment: Как вариант вешать обработчик на textView и вызавать в нем переход по нужному адресу. Но всегда этот вариант подойдет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде обязательно вызвать для этого `TextView`:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Убрать из разметки `android:autoLink="..."`, если задан - это для url-адресов, просто вставленных в тексте.
Дальше просто вставить ресурс в `TextView` в разметке:

```
android:text="@string/btn1javaA1"
```

или в коде:

```
tv.setText(R.string.btn1javaA1);
```

Если ресурс завёрнут в `<![CDATA[...]]>`, то тогда уже как у Вас:

```
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.btn1javaA1)));
```

Comment: все заработало, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Задайте в разметке вашего `TextView`:

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

И в коде сделайте так:

```
TextView tvLink = findViewById(R.id.tv_link);
String link = String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml("Кликните чтобы посетит сайт <br />" +
            "<a href='https://ru.stackoverflow.com//'>StackOverFlow.com</a>"));
tvLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
tvLink.setText(link);
```

Comment: так он просто будет реагировать на ссылки в тексте, а у меня они скрыты внутри текста. Например, "вот ссылка", но ее не видно.

Comment: @Виктор Отредактировал сообщение

Comment: А так он вместо ru-SO отправит на en-SO и то, только потому что оно задано как имя ссылки))).  `android:autoLink` не совместим с тэгом `<a>` - он выкидывает из него ссылку, оставляя только текст. А `String.valueOf` и `toString()`- вообще убивают все спаны

Comment: да, есть такое дело)